# z-index on absolutely and staticly positioned element element

Tags: css, position, z-index

How can you make absolutely positioned element appear under static element.

Z-index doesn't seem to work. The green box should be above the line (will be white).

http://jsfiddle.net/matthewabrman/pbL52gtj/

html:

```
<h3 class="line"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></h3>
```

css:

```
h3.line {
    font-size: 24px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    margin:30px;
    position: relative;
}

h3.line:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

h3.line > span {    
    background-color: #afa;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: in your case i think giving h3.line:after a z-index:-1 is sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Hope you are trying to get this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/pbL52gtj/2/)**

```
h3.line {
    font-size: 24px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    margin:30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:-1;
}

h3.line:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

h3.line > span {    
    background-color: #afa;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

**OR**  **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/pbL52gtj/3/)**

```
h3.line {
    font-size: 24px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    margin:30px;
    position: relative;

}

h3.line:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    z-index:-1;
}

h3.line > span {    
    background-color: #afa;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    }
```